# Split arary of structs of (key, value) into multiple columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame with one of the column being `array<struct<key:string, value: string>>`. I want to explode that column into multiple columns, where values of `key` elements becoming name of those columns, and values of `value` elements becoming the values of those `key`-based columns. Maybe a picture would illustrate this better:

Given column `c` with array of: `[[name, John], [role, admin], [created_at, 1555757657654]]`, I want to have a data frame of following structure:

```
+------+-------+---------------+
| name | role  | created_at    |
+------+-------+---------------+
| John | admin | 1555757657654 |
+------+-------+---------------+
```

To complicate matters further, different rows of column `c` might have different set of keys, and all of those keys must become columns, being set to null for the rows missing respective keys.

P.S. to address the [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), I want to efficiently query rows based on the keys and values. I tried to use `array_contains` function to check presence of keys in the array, but found performance to be insufficient.

Comment: I would be really curious to know the reason for downvote. As far as I can tell, this questions meets all the StackOverflow standards. I'm open for feedback and want to improve this question, but I need to know why it's considered bad, hence asking for a clarification for downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly, a `groupBy/pivot` transformation should be what you need:

```
case class KV(key: String, value: String)

val df = Seq(
  (1, Seq(KV("name", "John"), KV("role", "admin"))),
  (2, Seq(KV("name", "Rachel"), KV("role", "user"))),
  (3, Seq(KV("name", "Dave"), KV("created_at", "1555757657654")))
).toDF("id", "kvs")

df.
  withColumn("kv", explode($"kvs")).
  groupBy($"id").pivot($"kv.key").agg(first($"kv.value")).
  show
// +---+-------------+------+-----+
// | id|   created_at|  name| role|
// +---+-------------+------+-----+
// |  1|         null|  John|admin|
// |  3|1555757657654|  Dave| null|
// |  2|         null|Rachel| user|
// +---+-------------+------+-----+
```

Comment: Pivot is indeed what I've been looking for! Thanks.